# Counting the Number of Solutions Satisfying the Inequality, $x_1 + x_2 +\dots+ x_7 \leq 86$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I am trying to solve find the number of solutions to the inequality

$x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_7 \leq 86$

Where $x_i$'s are $\textbf{odd}$ positive integers, and the order matters.

If we ignore the constraint that $x_i$'s have to be odd, we can introduce another variable $x_8$ such that we have an equality: $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_7 + x_8 = 86$. Now a solution to this equation corresponds to a way of choosing $86$ items from a a set with $8$ elements such that there are $x_1$ items of type one, $x_2$ items of type two, etc. Thus, the number of solutions is equivalent to the number of $86-$combinations with repetition allowed from a set with $8$ elements, which is given by:

$\binom{86+8-1}{86} = \binom{93}{86} = \binom{93}{7}$

However, I am confused about how I can now find the number of solutions if $x_i$'s are odd. I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Hint: we can add $1$ to each $x_1, ...$ to force them to be even instead.

Comment: But if they are all odd, $\leq$ 86 cannot be correct (I mean equality).

Comment: @MathLover:  Why not?  Let all $x_i = 1$.

Comment: But there are $7$ of them (equality is what I am questioning).

Comment: Replace $x_i=2y_i+1, i=1..7$ and add $y_{8}$. Then use [generating functions](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/old/305/contentgeneratingfunctions.html) method for $$2y_1+2y_2+2y_3+...+2y_7+y_8=79$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all have to be odd, so put 1 into each of the 7 variables.

That leaves $86-7 = 79$

Every variable needs to remain odd so you can only change them by amounts of 2. So you discard the extra 1. That leaves 78. $78/2 = 39$ groups of 2 to distribute amount 7 variables.

Now do the same trick of adding an 8th variable for the $\le$:

${{8+39-1} \choose 39} = {46 \choose 39} = {46 \choose 7}$